# Need help finding continuity of this function : $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\left( \cos(xy) \right) ^ \frac{(x+2)\cot^2(xy)}{|{xy|}+1}$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

We got this question in our homework assignment with the prompt : Find continuity for $M_0=(0,0)$
$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
  \left( \cos(xy) \right) ^ \frac{(x+2)\cot^2(xy)}{|{xy|}+1} & (x,y) \ne (0,0) \\
  0 & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$

I'm having trouble finding a good way to substitute the $\cos(xy)$ and get an answer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @xpaul is right. Take ln on both sides (for f(x,y) ≠ 0) and then try solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: work on the following
$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{(x+2)\cot^2(xy)}{|{xy|}+1}\ln\left( \cos(xy) \right)=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)}\frac{x+2}{|{xy|}+1}\frac{\ln\left( \cos(xy) \right)}{\tan^2(xy)}=2\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\left( \cos (t) \right)}{\tan^2(t)}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: change $\left( \cos(xy) \right) ^ \frac{(x+2)\cot^2(xy)}{|{xy|}+1} $ with $2(\cos(xy)-1)\cot^2(xy)$ and then consider $t=xy$.